# how to fit columns in table even with vertical scrollbar

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I have a table with 3 columns. the second column content is smaller than the other two. so when I initialize the parent object(QMainWindow) I resize columns like this:

```
QSize tblSize = ui.tblUsers->size();

ui.tblUsers->setColumnWidth(0, 3 * tblSize .width() / 8);
ui.tblUsers->setColumnWidth(1, 2 * tblSize .width() / 8);
ui.tblUsers->setColumnWidth(2, 3 * tblSize .width() / 8);
```

everything is nice and good until the number of rows increases and a vertical scroll bar is added to the table. this scroll bar will take space and so the sum of width given to columns will exceed tables width( old width - scroll bar width). and because of that a horizontal scroll bar is added too which makes things very ugly.

so is there anyway to fix this problem? for example is there anyway to check to see if there will be a vertical scroll bar and then resize columns like this:

```
QSize tblSize = ui.tblUsers->size();

ui.tblUsers->setColumnWidth(0, 3 * (tblSize .width()-scrollBarSize) / 8);
ui.tblUsers->setColumnWidth(1, 2 * (tblSize .width()-scrollBarSize) / 8);
ui.tblUsers->setColumnWidth(2, 3 * (tblSize .width()-scrollBarSize) / 8);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `installEventFilter()` and intercept scroll bar `QShowEvent`, then resize columns on it:

```
int sz = tblSize.width();
if (ui.tblUsers->verticalScrollBar()->isVisible())
    sz -= ui.tblUsers->verticalScrollBar()->width();
ui.tblUsers->setColumnWidth(0, 3 * sz/8);
ui.tblUsers->setColumnWidth(1, 2 * sz/8);
ui.tblUsers->setColumnWidth(2, 3 * sz/8);
```

Also consider `ui.tblUsers->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn)`.

Comment: can you please explain more about installEventFilter or give link to a simple example about it. so far all the things that I read about QEvent, eventFilter , etc are too complicated for me to understand.BTW `ScrollBarAlwaysOn` is a very good Idea. also i did compute the sum of the  height of all rows plus horizontal header height and compared it to table height. with this I can check if scroll bar will appear or not.

Comment: See comment below

Answer (score 0):

Update 2

```
ui.tblUsers->installEventFilter(this);

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) {
    if(obj==ui.tblUsers) {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Show || event->type() == QEvent::Hide) {           
            recalculateColumnSizes(); //create such function
            return true;
        }
    }
    return __super::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```